# Quotation marks breaking Coldfusion display of WDDX

Tags: coldfusion, double-quotes, wddx

I am trying to display WDDX data using Coldfusion.

The data in the DB is:   8"x8"

When displayed on the front end, only the first '8' is visible.  When i remove the " from the string, it works fine.

Here is a code snippet:

```
<!---read WDDX data and output as var---> 
<cftry> 
<cfwddx action="wddx2cfml" input="#stImage.metainfo#" output="exif">    <cfcatch> 
<cfset exif=structnew()> 
<cfset exif.exif.artist=""> 
<cfset exif.exif['Image Description']=""> 
</cfcatch> 
</cftry> 

Description: <cfoutput>#exif.exif['Image Description']#</cfoutput>
```

Comment: Don't replace the quotes in the db.  They are there for a reason.  Provide a small bit of code that shows how this problem came about.

Comment: There are a lot of variables in the equation... Please post a small, example that reproduces the issue. [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Comments are meant to be temporary. Please **[edit]** your question.

Comment: Thanks for the input and guiding me along on how to use StackOverflow - i'm new here and am learning!!!

Comment: Sounds more like an issue with the display code, than cfwddx specifically. Might try using EncodeForHTML, which is usually a good idea anyway to protect against XSS injection..

Answer (score 1):

My buddy answered this one for me, and I wanted to post the answer here in case it helps anyone!  We replaced the " with &##34  (ascii format).

```
Description: 
<cfoutput>
#replace(exif.exif['Image Description'],'"',"&##34;",'all')#
</cfoutput>
```